# Linking libraries with a MinGW project in VS code

Tags: c, opengl, linker

I am using MinGW version 4.5.2 on windows 10. I am trying to link multiple libraries to a project in VS code. When I try run this command: `g++ main.c -o main.exe -I"C:\\Users\\USER\\Programming\\OPenGL Library\\glfw\\include\\glfw3.h" -L"C:\\Users\\USER\\Programming\\OpenGL Library\\glfw\\lib-mingw-w64\\"`. I get a compile error: `main.c:2:24: fatal error: GLFW\glfw3.h: No such file or directory` What is wrong with the command above that gives this linking error.  As far as I can tell I have pointed MinGW to the library and specified the header file. I am not sure what else I need to add to the command for link the GLFW library as well as other libraries such as GLEW or glm.

Comment: `Library\\glfw\\include\\glfw3.h` you should specify an include **directory** not a **file**.

Comment: This is not a linker error. You will probably get some, just not now. This is a *preprocessor* error.

Answer (score 0):

If your include directive looks like

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
```

you need to supply a path to a directory which itself contains a directory named GLFW.

Comment: I though by doing: -I"C:\\Users\\USER\\Programming\\OPenGL Library\\glfw\\" this pointed MinGW to the library. I have already put #include .g:FW/glfw3.h> in my file

Comment: @Dextron When the compiler looks for the header file glfw3.h, it appends GLFW/glfw3.h to the include path you supply. Do you have a directory named GLFW on your computer?

Comment: Yes I have a folder called GLFW on my system. Does it need to me in my project directory?

Comment: g++ main.c -o main.exe -l"C:\\Users\\USER\\Programming\\OpenGL_Library\\glfw\\include\\". Doesn't this point to my GLFW file on my system. after the include folder there is GLFW\\glfw3.h

Comment: @Dextron Yes, then the include path should be correct. The folder does not need to be in the project directory. Do you still get the same error?